# Give link to the text results in template

Tags: javascript, html

I was created a Django app and it produce IP address of corresponding domain name.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var input_string = $("#forminput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxexample_json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                client_response: input_string,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function(json) {
                $('#result').append('ServerResponse:' + json.server_response[][1]);
            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" name="example form" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="example" id="forminput" type="text">
        <input id="button" type="button" value="send to server"></input>
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Here if we enter "google.com" to the input form it produce output like this

```
ServerResponse:216.58.197.78
```

Here I want to get output in link format, ie

```
ServerResponse:link(216.58.197.78)
```

If I will click the link it directly go through 216.58.197.78 in localhost

**Output**
[image]

Comment: in the append you can put tags (like "a") and format it. Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: i need to get my output like  [216.58.197.78](http://www.example.com)

Comment: @sunny That is hyperlink like Itipacs mentioned. Refer to my answer below. Dont go ahead with `append` in your case it wont work since it is an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix is to set it as hyperlink. Replace the line from `success` function with below.

```
$('#result').html( '<a href ="'+json.server_response[][1]+'">'+json.server_response[][1]+ '</a>');
```

Using `append` will keep on appending to existing content. With multiple server calls you will get multiple links shown in result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this -

```
$('#result').append( 'ServerResponse:<a href ="' + json.server_response[][1] +'">link</a>(' + json.server_response[][1]+')');
```

replacing this in your existing code-

```
$('#result').append( 'ServerResponse:' + json.server_response[][1]);
```

Comment: Appending on div content will keep on appending subsequent values with multiple ajax responses.

Comment: your suggestion could be right but using append was't my idea its already in the code for question.. I just answered keeping in mind what was asked in question.

Comment: technically if you are getting output with your earlier code you should get output with this code also.. because nothing is changed in response only an <a> tag is added  to suit your requirements..

Comment: @ManojSalvi i got the answer.

Comment: @sunny Replace the success function statement. And choose append/html based on desired behavior (both will produce different outcome.)